# Powerforms submit - getting Docusign Envelope ID

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We are incorporating Powerforms into a Salesforce Community.  When a user completes a Powerform, we need to execute a trigger to write back to Salesforce.

My questions are related to attaching the completed Docusign envelope to the related Salesforce record:

1)  When we redirect from Powerforms, will we get the Docusign envelope ID?
2)  If so, can we insert a Docusign envelope record in Salesforce with that ID with the standard AppExchange package to tie the envelope to the record in Salesforce from which the Powerform was initiated?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged into DocuSign: Go To Admin>> Signing Settings>> In-Session Landing Pages

In-Session Landing Pages is used by Powerform to redirect the signer to the URL where you want Signer to redirects to. When Signer gets redirected then DocuSign populates URL like below:

```
{RedirectUrl}/?env={envelopeId}&pf={powerformId}&r={recipientId}
```

Alternatively and also recommended is to use [DocuSign Connect](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custom-connect-configuration-htm), where you subscribe for the event like Envelope Completed or Recipient Signed etc, once event occurs then DocuSign will push an XML message to your configured listener with the envelope related details. This is a better approach because with redirect there is a risk of the customer closing the browser or browser getting crashed before browser hits your app URL.